# Почему код не удаляет запись из бд?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

```
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port=3306,
    user="root",
    database = 'diss',
    password="")
    cur = cnx.cursor() 
    cur.execute("select owner from shop ORDER BY RAND()") 
    result = cur.fetchone()
    for x in result: 
        print(x); 
    query = f" DELETE  FROM shop  WHERE owner = {result[0]};"
    cur.execute(query)
    cnx.commit()
except:
    cnx.close() 
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813) 
    await channel.send(f'Ваш код:{ result[0]}',)
auto_send.start()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

В теории после запроса запись должна удаляться из бд, но ничего не происходит. Ошибок нет, query принимает правильный запрос.

Comment: Обсуждалось много раз. Замените на `cur.execute('delete from show where owner = %s', (result[0],))`

Comment: ошибок нет,- ведь весь код в try! так делать нельзя, особенно при недостаточном знании языка.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Спасибо, возможно поможет , а пока ошибка